# Simplest possible way to show two items NSTableView from code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

How I can create a code in XCode 4.2.1 what will create NSTableView and add just couple of items to it?

All what I wanted to do is:
1) Window where is NSTableView
2) I have an array of strings in NSArray which I like to show in that NSTableView
3) All of this should be done in code. So I don't want to learn how to add this action happen when you press button (I know already how to do actions when user click buttons etc), I just want that application launch -> draws the table where is those items from my array. That's it, nothing more.

And yeah I have understood that I do not add items to NSTableView directly. That is not the point in this question. I just mean that I want to show couple of items in that table but I have no and kind of clue WHERE I should add my data from my array.

I have tried to google for example pages for hours (just too many and have not find help) but I will always be stucked in the part when 
a) I must do something in the Interface Builder and the images of the interface builder are from version 2.x or 3.x and I have 4.2.1 and it is totally different (new to XCode...). Surely I have drawn my TableView element to UI but I mean delegations etc. Are those necessary at all? Can those be made from source code?
b) Code just does not work anymore because language (Cocoa or Objective-C, I don't know) has changed and I don't know how and what I have to do to make it work on newest version of XCode.
c) There is too much different ways told: "use binding", "you must create new class what is NSTableViewDataSource" etc. I have no any kind of clue what is preferred way, is another way optional or it is "you should use this because another is going deprecated soon" or something.

So please, can somebody give help in step-by-step what I exactly have to do? Should I create some bindings? If so, how and where? Do I have to create DataSource component myself? Are those ways valid any more? If I have to, how I can create it? Create a new class and implement it as a NSTableViewDataSource and then use it? Is that way valid any more and if it is, can sombody show code what is as simple as possible?

I have also checked Apple Documentation page many many times, checked those example codes but there is just too much totally unrelated stuff that I just don't understand at this point so they are totally useless (I mean, I don't know what is required for this task, what are not etc.

I would be very happy if somebody can help short tutorial step-by-step what to do. I mean "step-by-step" like:
1) Create new project
2) Draw NSTableView in project
3) Create new class with this name
4) Write this code: blah blah blah
5) Create another class with this name
6) Write this code
7) Run and see those items from array in NSTableView using (bindings/datasource/whatever is preferred).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your tableview needs a datasource. Your datasource is a custom class, it implements the "NSTableViewDataSource" protocol. This protocol contains a few methods that you can use to tell the tableview what data you got.

this includes the objectValue ( the value of the NSCell that is displaying your data on the specified row, and a method that returns the amount of rows the tableview has ( the amount of items in your array ).

Here a tutorial I found by googling:
[CocoaDev.com NSTableView tutorial](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableViewTutorial)

You can also implement the **NSTableViewDelegate** protocol which allows some greater control. Like what rows you can select, or some extra configuring of a custom tableview cell.

I must say that back in the day when I started developing desktop applications ( only had experience with web technologies ) that this design pattern confused me as well. Hope you will get your mind round it soon.

Comment: Thanks, but I have checked that page already but I did not understood. I did not understand this part in the beginning:"You will need to do a little extra work when adding a table view to a nib file: you need to hook up your controller object as the table view's dataSource. You do this by control-dragging from your table view to your controller object. Once this connection is established, the table view will ask your controller for new data, notify your controller when data changes, and so on. " <-- So what is that "controller object"? Where I do get that?How I will create that, is it a class?

Comment: Yeah it is the object I was talking about in my answer. [tableViewOutlet setDatasource:self]; in your controller class works as well.

Comment: And when I drag my tableView item to source code with Ctrl + drag and create it as a outlet, then what? Could you give step-by-step what to do that I can see some items there, I am totally confused about this still... (coming from PHP ;)

Comment: I made a small video. It will be converted to a useable format in about 30 minutes. Please be patient

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying that, but the packaging of video has made some parts unreadable :/ For example in 1:26 I cannot see what there reads, font goes too blurry in that video? Is that because of vimeo? I tried to check that with Safari and Chrome (with and without flash, eg. HTML5 video and Flash version) but could not read it (in 13" inch display in fullscreen mode) :/

Comment: Just for information, I finally made it \o/. I will try to write some day a blog post about it so hopefully it will help somebody other too. Thank you very mcuh for help!